# Received dispute credit and refund

Tags: credit-card, dispute, airline

I had booked a flight with an airline through my chase credit card. It was a connecting flight and the airline canceled one of the connecting flights but didn't cancel and refund my trip. So I tried to cancel my entire trip but airline didn't allow me to do so without a heavy penalty.
So I filed a dispute on credit card and I was credited back the amount. Three weeks later, airline issued a partial refund and I now have both the credit as well as refund on my card.
What should be my next step? Wait for chase to take back the credit? Or contact them through email or phone?

EDIT: The refund amount is a little lesser than original transaction amount since the transaction was in foreign currency and due to the fluctuating currency rate, I got a lesser amount refunded. Do I have an option to get the difference amount back too?

Answer (score 2):

I have dome something similar before, but it was with a hotel room.  *Most likely* what will happen is that Chase will contact the airline alerting them of the dispute. When the airline informs them that you were issued a refund, Chase will cancel the dispute and reverse the credit.

It certainly can't hurt to let them know what is happening, but I would not expect you to get both credits "free and clear". Make sure you have enough cash to pay off the card once the charge hits so that you don't incur any late fees or interest and compound the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you agree that the refund is the correct amount, I would recommend contacting Chase and canceling the dispute. It's cleaner, and will undoubtedly save some people's time from both the airline and Chase from having to confirm it was refunded, document it, provide the info to Chase, etc.

Chase has a [phone number](https://www.chase.com/personal/credit-cards/dispute) for exactly this purpose:

> To cancel a dispute, call us at 1-888-489-8452. We also accept operator relay calls. If you're deaf, hard of hearing, or have a speech disability, call 711 for assistance.

Comment: Actually the refund is a little lesser than original amount since the transaction was in foreign currency and due to the fluctuating currency rate, I got a lesser amount refunded. Edited the question.

Comment: That's unfortunate. From the airline's point of view, it seems they refunded the correct charged amount. In theory, you could have gained a little bit had it fluctuated the other way. If it's a small difference I would just let it go.